# How to solve error : Cannot use a scalar value as an array

Tags: php, mysql

I have this Php Code :-

```
<?php
$num=3;
    for($i=0; $i<=$num ; $i++)
  {
$query_result = ("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE sub_id='$i' ");
$result[$i] = mysql_query($query_result, $storecon) or die(mysql_error()); 
$row_result[$i] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result[$i]);
  }
?>
```

It gave me this error :Cannot use a scalar value as an array
I want to make queries with same names like result1 , result2 ..etc

Comment: By select anything from your table you must loop through it. Also, don't use mysql, use mysqli instead since mysql is deprecated. moreover, before using $result[$i], you must define it as an array :)

Comment: Why not `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE sub_id IN (1,2,3)`?

Comment: Thank you ... just define :)

Comment: @Digital Chris because $num not equal 3 really it just for example

Comment: Exactly. So create a list of ID's, and call the sql one time.

Answer (score 1):

This could solve your problem.
If the $sub_id field is a number you mustn't quote it.

```
<?php

$num=3;
$result = array();
$row_result = array();

for($i=0; $i<=$num ; $i++)
{
    $query_result = ("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE sub_id='$i' ");
    $result[$i] = mysql_query($query_result, $storecon);

    if (empty($result[$i]))
        die(mysql_error());

    $row_result[$i] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result[$i]);
}

var_dump($row_result); //Show the result
```

As suggested by @briosheje, don't use mysql but mysqli